# Regex capture first words before character subsequently - oracle

Tags: regex, oracle

How do i capture the  word before the = sign, there is another equal sign in the URL which i do not want to capture

```
 SELECT
  REGEXP_SUBSTR('TType=SEND|Status=OK|URL=min://j?_a=3&ver=1.1|day=3',
                '([^|]+)=', 1,1,NULL,1) "TType"    
  FROM DUAL;
```

From the above string `TType=SEND|Status=OK|URL=min://j?_a=3&ver=1.1|day=3`

I only want `TType,Status,URL,day`

Note: The string has a pipe delimiter | for the parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
SELECT
  TRIM(',' FROM REGEXP_REPLACE('TType=SEND|Status=OK|URL=min://j?_a=3&ver=1.1|day=3',
                '=[^|]+($|\|)', ',')) "TType"    
  FROM DUAL
```

The `REGEXP_REPLACE` will find and replace with a comma all occurrences of a `=[^|]+($|\|)` pattern that matches

- `=` - a `=` char
- `[^|]+` - one or more chars other than `|`
- `($|\|)` - either end of string or `|`.

See an [online demo](https://rextester.com/HAUMW89158).

Comment: i have asked [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66154220/regex-capture-first-words-before-character-subsequently-postgresql)  but in postgresql

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
select  level as ord,
        regexp_substr('TType=SEND|Status=OK|URL=min://j?_a=3&ver=1.1|day=3',
                      '(\||^)([^|=]*)', 1,level,null,2) as token    
from    dual
connect by level <= 
        regexp_count('TType=SEND|Status=OK|URL=min://j?_a=3&ver=1.1|day=3',
                     '(\||^)([^|=]*)')
;

ORD TOKEN   
--- --------
  1 TType   
  2 Status  
  3 URL     
  4 day
```

In a more complex situation (where you may have several input strings, distinguished by an `ID` of some sort), the query is a bit more complex, but the "regexp" part is the same.

Note that this query finds all the "attribute names", not just the first one. The regular expression searches for each "attribute-value pair" beginning (either the beginning of the string or a pipe character, `(\||^)` - note that the verbatim pipe character must be escaped), and from there, it takes the longest continuous substring of characters **other than** pipe character and equal sign `([^|=]*)` and it returns the *second* capture group.

In particular, this means that if a "pair" doesn't have an equal sign, the whole substring ("between pipe characters") will be returned. For example: if the input is

```
'TType=SEND|Status=OK|blah blah|day=3'
```

then the third token returned by the query will be all of `'blah blah'`. That can be changed as needed (or, alternatively, if you know that all such substings always contain an equal sign, the issue is moot).