# Regex capture first words before character subsequently - Postgresql

Tags: regex, postgresql

With refference to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66153909/regex-capture-first-words-before-character-subsequently#66154015) but now in postgress
How do i capture the word before the = sign, there is another equal sign in the URL which i do not want to capture

```
SELECT
  TRIM(',' FROM REGEXP_REPLACE('TType=SEND|Status=OK|URL=min://j?_a=3&ver=1.1|day=3',
                '=[^|]+($|\|)', ',')) "PARAMS"
```

From the above string `TType=SEND|Status=OK|URL=min://j?_a=3&ver=1.1|day=3`

I only want `TType,Status,URL,day`

Note: The string has a pipe delimiter | for the parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```sql
SELECT ARRAY_TO_STRING (
 ARRAY (
   SELECT REGEXP_MATCHES (
      'TType=SEND|Status=OK|URL=min://j?_a=3&ver=1.1|day=3',
      '(?:\||^)(\w+)=', 'g'
   )
 ), ',') as PARAMS
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TRc6Rn/1).

**NOTE**: `REGEXP_MATCHES` returns only capturing group value if a capturing group is defined in the regex pattern. Here, the pattern means

- `(?:\||^)` - (a non-capturing group matching either) `|` or start of string
- `(\w+)` - Capturing group 1 (the actual return value): any one or more alphanumeric chars
- `=` - a `=` char.

The `REGEXP_MATCHES` result is case to an array first and then conveted to a string with `ARRAY_TO_STRING`.

Answer (score 1):

[step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f3d25d18f5fa808e003efeb8a722fc8a)

```
SELECT
    string_agg(                                          -- 3
        split_part(elements, '=', 1),                    -- 2        
        ','
    )
FROM mytable,
    regexp_split_to_table(mystring, '\|') as elements    -- 1
```

1. Split the string into params like `A=B`. Move every into a separate record
2. Split these elements at the `=` character and return the first split
3. Finally aggregate all these first splits to a string list.